# Can I Dynamically create class instances?

Tags: c#, oop

I am creating a program to check if files exist in different network locations. My program reads the data from an external source where every instance of files to check has the parameters File Path, Files to check, Boolean to append date to the end of file names, Time to run check and a list of email addresses to send an email with the results to. I have a class File Data:

```
class FileData
    {
        private string path;

        private string[] files;

        private string[] successEmail;

        private string[] failureEmail;

        private bool appendDate;

        private DateTime runTime;

        public string Path
        {
            get { return path; }
            set { path = value; }
        }

        public string[] Files
        {
            get { return files; }
            set { files = value; }
        }

        public string[] SuccessEmail
        {
            get { return successEmail; }
            set { successEmail = value; }

        }

        public string[] FailureEmail
        {
            get { return failureEmail; }
            set { failureEmail = value; }
        }


        public DateTime RunTime
        {
            get { return runTime; }
            set { runTime = value; }
        }
}
```

I would like to dynamically create an instance of this class as the number of instances needed will likely change from day to day. Is it possible to create these instances dynamically like so:

```
FileData <DynamicName> = new FileData(data to pass in)
```

Am I looking at this the wrong way? I know I could use a nested Dictionary, is that the right approach?

Comment: This question's a little confusing; are you trying to assign a new instance to a dynamic variable name?

Comment: You should be using some type of collection/list/array. As to how you can do that no one can tell you until you post the code that makes use of this class. Also look into Auto Properties, it makes for less clutter in your code.

Comment: It can be achieved with reflection API

Comment: isn't that what constructors are for?

Comment: @levelone yes, I am trying to create an instance of this class with a dynamic variable name.

Comment: @Igor I see I have no problem creating a collection if I must, I just thought using the class may make it easier to access the data.

Comment: @user3839756 - don't confuse your terms. A class is a definition and an instance of a class is called an object. Your **class** above `FileData` is good in that you can use that and create a strongly typed collection. That collection can then be assigned either to a field or a property of some other class that does something with it. For example, you could have a `List<FileData>` instance.

Comment: You probably want to create a collection of the type of your class, like `List<FileData>`, or if you need a name, `Dictionary<string, FileData>`

Comment: @Igor Thanks this is becoming a little more clear, so instead of creating a new object I would create a list of objects. If I understand correctly the code would be like: 
fileData newData = new fileData()
newData.path ... (add the rest of my data)
myList.Add(newData)
(then lop through and add all the objects I need)

Comment: @user3839756 - Correct. Create your list/collection/array/(whatever) and add to it in your loop or through some other event (maybe you are watching the file system).